# "Destination drive will be ovewritten" when creating an image from a partition

Tags: disk-image, norton-ghost, ghost

I want to make an .vmdk image of a partition of my primary disk with Norton Ghost 12, and put the resulting image on an external USB drive. I select `Local > Partition > To Image`, then the drive I want to extract the partition from, then the partition. After that, I select the right path to the resulting .vmdk file, it summerizes the partitions that will be saved, and then I have this message :

```
Question: (1831)

Proceed with disk clone ?
Destination drive will be ovewritten.
```

I don't want my destination drive to be overwritten ! What is going on ? How can I be sure that it will not erase anything on any of my disks, just create my image ?

Comment: the space of the image to be clone ON THE DESTINATION will be overwritten only thing that comes to mind otherwise (bu not sure it can make a .vmdk file is to cp -rRHPp /path/to/source  /path/to/destination

Comment: if it didn't ask you for a destination image path, then don't do it.

Comment: I would be very careful when reading such a message. It is unusual for programs to warn you like that when creating just the image... Maybe get some other external USB drive to test what Norton Ghost is doing?

Comment: @Frank Thomas : it actually asks me the destination image path

Comment: @Slizzered I also noticed that the same message (with the same question code '1831') is displayed for any operation. It looks like a default warning message, but I'm going to play it safe and I'll test with a second USB key

Answer (score 0):

After testing with another USB key, it looks like that this operation doesn't erase the disk, as indicated. When any operation with Ghost is being started, the same message, with the same question code, is printed, whatever if the operation is going to drop the entire destination disk or just create another file on it. 
Be careful to triple check which operation you choose, this message invites you to do so.